# VBA Classes - Custom Properties

Tags: vba, class, ms-word, coordinates, docusignapi

tldr: can you scavenge properties from other types of objects?

My firm is integrating with DocuSign.  We need to tell DocuSign where to (dynamically) place the signature markers on dozens of documents that are created and uploaded (and different every time).

We will have a 'keyword' or bookmark that will indicate where the signature needs to be.  The crux here is to get each signature location's page number, x-pos and y-pos.

The .Top and .Left properties for the Shape object are perfect.  I'd rather not inundate the documents with placeholder shapes everywhere, however. I'd rather have just bookmarks or best yet a keyword (like @@SignatureHere) to search for and procure location.

I've explored cursor position (bad).  Now I'm interested in creating a Range class that leverages the .Top and .Left properties of the Shape object.  Is this possible?

```
Public MyRange As Range

Public Property Get Top() As Long
'returns the top position of the range
Top = MyRange.Top '<---this doesn't work because .Top is not a member of the Range object
End Property

Public Property Get NumPage() As Integer
'returns the page number of the start of the range
End Property
```

Comment: A custom property might work.